# React testing with asynchronous setState

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs

I'm new to React testing and I'm having a hard time figuring out the following issue:

I'm trying to simulate an input onChange event. It's a text input that filters the results in a table. `InteractiveTable` has a controlled input field (`ControlledInput`) and an instance of Facebook's `FixedDataTable`.

This is the test:

```
let filter = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(component, ControlledInput);
let input = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(filter, 'input');
input.value = 'a';
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
console.log(component.state);
```

On input change the component updates its state with the value of the input, but since `setState` is asynchronous, here the console.log will log out the previous state, and I can't query the structure of the component for testing, because it's not updated yet. What am I missing?

Edit: to be clear, if I make the assertion in a setTimeout, it will pass, so it's definitely a problem with the asynchronous nature of setState.

I found one solution, where I overwrite the `componentDidUpdate` method of the component:

```
component.componentDidUpdate = () => {
  console.log(component.state); // shows the updated state
  let cells = ReactTestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(component, Cell);
  expect(cells.length).toBe(30);
  done();
};
```

This wouldn't be possible if the component had its own componentDidUpdate method, so it's not a good solution. This seems to be a very common problem, yet I find no solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when I run into similar scenarios when testing, I try to break things apart a little. In your current test, (depending on your flavor of test framework),  you could mock the component's `setState` method, and simply ensure that it's called with what you expect when you simulate a change.

If you want further coverage, in a different test you could call the real `setState` with some mock data, and then use the [callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) to make assertions about what's rendered, or ensure other internal methods are called.

OR: If your testing framework allows for [simulating async](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jest-runallticks) stuff, you could try calling that too and test the whole thing in one go.

Comment: That's one solution, but not too black-boxy, where I'm testing how it works instead of just the results of a user interaction in itself.

Comment: Hmm. Yea, that's true.   What testing tools are you using?   The approach may vary a little depending on that.